# The Highscore wont save

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Hope you will help me. When  run the app It was working, but then when, I run it again it is not working and theres no error to be found. I dont know why, but sometimes it work but sometimes it not working.  Here is my code....**

> public class filldisResult extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> ImageView imghome;
> TextView txtTotalQuesion, txtWrong, txtCorrect;
> int totalQuestion, correct, wrong;
>
>
>
>
>     public static final String SCOREPREFERENCE = "shared_preference";
>     public static final String TOTALQUESTION = "total_score_preference";
>     public static final String WRONG = "wrong_preference";
>     public static final String CORRECT = "correct_preference";
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_filldis_result);
>
>     imghome = findViewById(R.id.img_homeS);
>
>     txtCorrect = findViewById(R.id.txtCorrectQues);
>     txtWrong = findViewById(R.id.txtWrongQues);
>     txtTotalQuesion = findViewById(R.id.txtTotalQuestions);
>
>     loadHighScore();
>     updateCorrectAnswer(correct);
>     updateTotalScore(totalQuestion);
>     updateWrongAnswer(wrong);
>
>     imghome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             Intent intent = new Intent(filldisResult.this, filldisPlayScreen.class);
>             startActivity(intent);
>             finish();
>         }
>     });
>
> }
> private void updateTotalScore(int scoreToUpdate){
>
>     if(scoreToUpdate > totalQuestion){
>
>         totalQuestion = scoreToUpdate;
> ```
>
> SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE,MODE_PRIVATE);
> SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
> editor.putInt(TOTALQUESTION,totalQuestion);
> editor.apply();
> }
> }
> private void updateCorrectAnswer(int scoreToUpdate){
>
> ```
>     if(scoreToUpdate > correct){
>
>     correct = scoreToUpdate;
>     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE,MODE_PRIVATE);
>     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
>     editor.putInt(CORRECT,correct);
>     editor.apply();
>     }
>
> }
>
> enter code here
> private void updateWrongAnswer(int scoreToUpdate){
>
>     if(scoreToUpdate > wrong){
>
>         wrong = scoreToUpdate;
>         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE,MODE_PRIVATE);
>         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
>         editor.putInt(WRONG,wrong);
>         editor.apply();
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> private void loadHighScore() {
>
> ```
>     SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesScore = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
>      totalQuestion = sharedPreferencesScore.getInt(TOTALQUESTION, 0);
>      Log.i(" Total Questions :", " " + totalQuestion);
>      txtTotalQuesion.setText("" + totalQuestion);
>
>
>     SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesCorrect = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
>     correct = sharedPreferencesCorrect.getInt(CORRECT, 0);
>     Log.i("Correct Answer :", " " + correct);
>     txtCorrect.setText("" + correct);
>
>
>     SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesWrong = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
>     wrong = sharedPreferencesWrong.getInt(WRONG, 0);
>     Log.i("Wrong Answer :", " " + wrong);
>     txtWrong.setText("" + wrong);
>
>
> } }
> ```

my xml...

> <LinearLayout

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context=".filldisResult"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Score List"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtScoreText"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Total Questions :"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="00"
                android:id="@+id/txtTotalQuestions"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Score :"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="00"
                android:id="@+id/txtCorrectQues"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Wrong Answer :"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="00"
                android:id="@+id/txtWrongQues"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_for_settings_and_score"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_homeS"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `commit()` your editor before do `apply()`

Comment: Glad to hear this! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commit()` your `editor` before do `apply()`

```
 if(scoreToUpdate > correct){
        correct = scoreToUpdate;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(CORRECT,correct);
        editor.commit(); //insert here
        editor.apply();
        }

    private void updateWrongAnswer(int scoreToUpdate){
        if(scoreToUpdate > wrong) {
            wrong = scoreToUpdate;
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SCOREPREFERENCE,MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(WRONG,wrong);
            editor.commit();  //insert here
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
```